# Running BERT SQUAD model on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, stanford-nlp, bert-language-model, squad

I am using the BERT Squad model to ask the same question on a collection of documents (>20,000). The model currently runs on my CPU and it takes around a minute to process a single document - which means that I'll need several days to complete the program.

I was wondering if I could speed this up by running the model on a GPU. However, I am new to GPUs and I don't know how to send these inputs and the model to the device (Titan xp).

The code is borrowed from Chris McChormick.

```
import torch
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertForQuestionAnswering
from transformers import BertTokenizer

model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')
```

'question' and 'answer_text' are the question and the context string respectively.

```
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, answer_text)

    # ======== Set Segment IDs ========
    # Search the input_ids for the first instance of the `[SEP]` token.
    sep_index = input_ids.index(tokenizer.sep_token_id)

    if len(input_ids)>512:
        input_ids=input_ids[:512]
  
    num_seg_a = sep_index + 1
    num_seg_b = len(input_ids) - num_seg_a

    # Construct the list of 0s and 1s.
    segment_ids = [0]*num_seg_a + [1]*num_seg_b

    # There should be a segment_id for every input token.
    assert len(segment_ids) == len(input_ids)

    # ======== Evaluate ========
    # Run our example through the model.
    outputs = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]), # The tokens representing our input text.
                    token_type_ids=torch.tensor([segment_ids]), # The segment IDs to differentiate question from answer_text
                    return_dict=True) 

    start_scores = outputs.start_logits
    end_scores = outputs.end_logits
```

I know that I can send the model to the GPU using model.tocuda(). But how do I send the inputs, train the model, and the retreive output from the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I'll answer anyway in the hope that maybe it will help someone.
You can copy each tensor to the GPU using the `to` method.
For example your batch contains 4 pytorch tensors: input ids, attention masks, segment ids and labels

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
b_seg_ids = batch[2].to(device)
b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
```

Then,You can use the `.cpu()` to transfer the logits and labels from the gpu back to the cpu. In example;

```
start_logits = start_logits.detach().cpu()
end_logits = end_logits.detach().cpu()
```

or similarly to(device) you can use

```
start_logits = start_logits.to('cpu')
end_logits = end_logits.to('cpu')
```

Note that: Since you will be using them in the model, you will probably need to add .numpy() to the end and convert them to a numpy array.

Source:https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/time-to-transform-gpu-to-cpu-with-cpu/18856